# Редактирование файла в си

Tags: c

Есть бинарный файл, будем считать, что там лежат числа типа long long. Нужно найти наибольшее из них и заменить его на LLONG_MIN. Как это сделать?

Comment: Читать и запоминать текущую позицию наибольшего. Потом перейти туда и записать туда LLONG_MIN. Что сложного?

Comment: А разве в таком случае не будет затерт весь последующий файл?

Comment: Нет, не будет..

Comment: [open](https://linux.die.net/man/2/open)/[read](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read)/[lseek](https://linux.die.net/man/2/lseek)/[write](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write)